# How can I gain access to the button of my dialog box that has a partial MVC view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I’m trying to access the close button of my dialog box.  I would like to use the click event of the button.  I’ve tried this:

```
 dialogButton = $('#my-dialog').dialog.find("button");
```

I’ve tried this from examples I’ve seen but it hasn’t work for me.  How can I gain access to the button of my dialog box that has a partial MVC view?

```
 $(function () {


        $('#my-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,

            title: "Schedule",
            resizable: false,
            modal: false,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('.modal').click(function () {
            $('#my-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });


    dialogButton = $('#my-dialog').dialog.find("button");
    $('#my-dialog').click(function () {

        alert(dialogButton);
    });

    });
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to get to the button, since you already have a handler function created when you call `$('#my-dialog').dialog()` the first time in your code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `#my-dialog button` is already part of the DOM, then the correct syntax to select the `button` element inside of `#my-dialog` is: `$('#my-dialog').find('button')`.

However, chances are that the `button` element doesn't exist yet in the DOM when you're trying to grab `dialogButton` -- a user first has to open the dialog. If that's the case, use the [jQuery `on` method](https://api.jquery.com/on/), like so:

```
$('#my-dialog').on('click', 'button', function() {
    alert($(this));
});
```